# Save a non formulated version of a spreadsheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formula, save-as

The below VBA works great which was assisted by another user. The issue I have now, and hopefully the last, is that when the original spreadsheet is updated, which collects data from other sources, the newly saved spreadsheet also updates. Not ideal when trying to track purchase orders etc. Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" ( _
ByVal lpPath As String) As Long

Sub Check_CreateFolders_YEAR_SO_WODRAFT()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Path1 As String
    Dim Path2 As String
    Dim Path3 As String
    Dim Path4 As String
    Dim myfilename As String
    Dim fpathname As String

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jobs Sheet").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
    Path1 = "C:\Users\jackson.wills\Sparter Ltd\Engineer Order - e-Board"
    Path2 = Range("A23")
    Path3 = Range("I3")
    Path4 = Range("I4")
    myfilename = Range("I3").Value & Range("A1").Value & Range("I4").Value & Range("A1").Value & Range("AA1").Value
    fpathname = Path1 & "\" & Path2 & "\" & Path3 & "\" & Path4 & "\" & myfilename & ".xlsx"

    If Dir("C:\Users\jackson.wills\Sparter Ltd\Engineer Order - e-Board\" & Path2 & "\" & Path3 & "\" & Path4, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MakeSureDirectoryPathExists "C:\Users\jackson.wills\Sparter Ltd\Engineer Order - e-Board\" & Path2 & "\" & Path3 & "\" & Path4 & "\"
        ' MkDir Path:="C:\Users\jackson.wills\Sparter Ltd\Engineer Order - e-Board\" & Path2
        ' MkDir Path:="C:\Users\jackson.wills\Sparter Ltd\Engineer Order - e-Board\" & Path2 & "\" & Path3
        ' MkDir Path:="C:\Users\jackson.wills\Sparter Ltd\Engineer Order - e-Board\" & Path2 & "\" & Path3 & "\" & Path4
        MsgBox "Completed"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sales Order Folder Already Exists so we'll save it in there"
    End If

    MsgBox "You are trying to save the file to:" & vbCrLf & fpathname
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=fpathname & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: I should mention I wish to retain the VBA element. Thanks again

Comment: Note, if I understand "wish to retain the VBA element" correctly, you will have to save as xlsm and not xlsx.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, just do something like this:

After the line

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jobs Sheet").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
```

add these lines:

```
With wb.Sheets("Jobs Sheet")
    .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
End With
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the quick turnaround, I don’t suppose you could incorporate it into the existing code? Like most on here, I’m not great at this and would only come back to you with other questions because I’ve done it wrong lol

Comment: Add those last three lines (the `With...End With` block) right after the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jobs Sheet").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)` in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give it ago. When I do, I’ll let you know if it works or not. Thanks again

Comment: This works great. Is there anyway I can exempt cell H6 from what you suggested? 

Cell H6 has a condition on it so an email is produced when it is altered. This is happening prematurely, I would like this to still be available in the newly saved version. Any ideas? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Is it a formula then in H6? Or do you have a worksheet change event?

Comment: Excuse my novice approach. On the original worksheet, right click the tab name, view code. In there I have a code to monitor H6 so when the newly saved version is then edited by another colleague, it will send an email. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That does make sense - is the code a `Worksheet_Change` or a `Worksheet_Calculate`?

Comment: And you saw my comment to save as xlsm, right? Is the event firing? You might need to toggle `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` and then back to `True`

Comment: I didn’t see that, sorry. The file is being saved as:

Comment: “And you saw my comment to save as xlsm, right? Is the event firing? You might need to toggle Application.EnableEvents to False and then back to True”

Comment: Sorry I don’t follow

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correctly, add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the  `.Value = .Value`. After it, add `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: so the worksheet change isn’t firing when saving the new file but when H6 in the newly saved file is now altered the email command isn’t activating..... sorry Ben, I know this is trivial and I appreciate your time

Comment: Hmm. Maybe ask this as a new question, and include your worksheet change code. This sounds like a different issue.